# How to check the nearest html tag by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about the javascript. I have the following html code, 4 buttons, 2 to highlight the color, and 1 to clear the selected color, and 1 to clear all the color.

When the user uses the mouse to highlight the text and click the 'red' button, e.g. My name is John, the selected text will be highlight to be red (assume there is a class called 'red').

e.g.

```html
// Before select the text and click the button
    <p id='text'>
    My name is John,
    I live in ABC and I have a car.
    I like to play TV game.
    </p>

// After select the text and click the button
    <p id='text'>
    <span class='red'>My name is John</span>,
    I live in ABC and I have a car.
    I like to play TV game.
    </p>
```

When the user clicks the 'clear all' button, all the color will disappear.

And the 'Clear' button (I don't know this part), when the user selected the color-ed text, e.g. My name is John, and then click the 'clear', the color will disappear.

e.g.

```html
// Before select the color-ed text and click the button
    <p id='text'>
    <span class='red'>My name is John</span>,
    I live in ABC and I have a car.
    I like to play TV game.
    </p>

// After select the color-ed text and click the button
    <p id='text'>
    My name is John,
    I live in ABC and I have a car.
    I like to play TV game.
    </p>
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
// javascript
function colour(colour) {
var selectTxt =    
   window.getSelection() ||
   document.getSelection() ||
   (document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : ''),
   targetHTML = document.getElementById('text');
   targetHTML.innerHTML =
     targetHTML.innerHTML.replace(
              RegExp(selectTxt),
              '<span class="colour">'+selectTxt+'</span>');

}

function clear_colour() {
     // I don't know how to do in here??
}

function clear_colour_all() {
    var para = document.getElementById('text');
    para.innerHTML = 'My name is John, I live in ABC and I have a car. I like to play TV game.';
}
```

```html
// HTML
<input type="button" onclick="colour('red')" value='red'/> 
<input type="button" onclick="colour('yellow')" value='yellow'/> 
<input type="button" onclick="clear_colour()" value='Clear'/> 
<input type="button" onclick="clear_colour_all()" value='Clear All'/> 

<p id='text'>
My name is John,
I live in ABC and I have a car.
I like to play TV game.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use jQuery for resolving cross browser issues and handle this much more elegantly. But on a pure JS level, a crude way of doing it would be:

```
function clear_colour() {
   targetHTML = document.getElementById('text');
   targetHTML.innerHTML = targetHTML.innerText ? targetHTML.innerText : targetHTML.textContent;
}
```

*Note:* `innerText` works on IE only. Other browsers (FF/Webkit based) use standard compliant `textContent` property.

Using jQuery:

```
function clear_colour() {
   var clearText = $('#text span.colour').text();
   $('#text').html(clearText);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I try it in Chrome and it is work and would you mind to provide the jQuery version as well? it helps me to learn more.

Comment: Instead of `innerText` & `textContent` use `.nodeValue` which works across all browsers

Comment: @Raynos: `nodeValue` is tricky cause you've to do something like `targetHTML.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue` to get the text (the 2nd `firstChild` is the text node in the `span`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way working on the most recent Chrome and Firefox:

```
function clear_colour(){
    var selectTxt =    
       window.getSelection() ||
       document.getSelection() ||
       (document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : ''),
        //get the span
        span = (selectTxt.anchorNode || selectTxt.extentNode).parentNode,
        //set a new text node
        clearedTxt = document.createTextNode(span.innerHTML);
        //replace the span with the new text node
        span.parentNode.replaceChild(clearedTxt, span);
};
```